# AngularJS not loading templates in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use Angular with my Codeigniter project. The problem is that it doesn't load the proper template file through angular router.

In the root instead of showing `templateUrl: 'index.php/welcome/home'`, it loads the `index.php/welcome`. It loads the index page inside the controller instead of the ones I have specified.

Below is my code:

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('MyCtrl', ['ngRoute', "ui.bootstrap.modal"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index.php/welcome/home',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/user', {
        templateUrl: 'index.php/user/account',
        controller: 'userController'
    })

});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'main con';
});

app.controller('userController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'user con!';
});
```

**Welcome** controller in Codeigniter:

```
 public function home(){
     $this->load->view('home');
 }
```

Can someone tell me why this is not working and what I have done wrong?

Comment: When you request directly "index.php/welcome/home" does it load your template?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin Yep.. When i access the url directly it loads the template